# Simple Slackbot to Query Airtable

Tags: slack, airtable

How can I build a very simple Slackbot that queries an Airtable dataset? No need for natural language at this point, I just need Slacked search term to equal Airtable field A and then return Airtable field B.

Equally useful, would be a Slack slash command, say /glossary [A], that pings Airtable and returns the found B value based in user string A.

Any/all help appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you to do couple tutorials to understand Slack API. For example [this](https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/build-first-slack-bot-python.html) or [this](https://github.com/slackapi/Slack-Python-Onboarding-Tutorial/blob/master/README.md#pythonboarding-bot)

Comment: @acenright Please be advised slackoverflow is a site for helping with specific coding problems, not a coding service. So stating some general application requirements will not get you anywhere. Almost every solution for the many requirements you posted will include coding a Slack app. Please refer to any of the great beginners [tutorials](https://api.slack.com/tutorials) on how to create apps for Slack.